# Virtual Machine Manager - Make VM believe its running on physical machine

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I use Fedora and i have a Windows 10 VM which i want to make believe its running on Hardware, physically, without it knowing its a VM.

How can i do this?

Background:
I try to get WSL2+HyperV running inside my Windows 10 VM, but it every time goes into windows restore mode after the reboot. I suspect it somehow knows its running virtually, and fails.

I do have nested virtualization enabled on the host for kvm_intel.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1389159/144961

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks. i followed your post, but the <cpu host...> config does not stick. after i exit virsh and start the vm, the setting is reverted to its original state..